# Compact complex non-Kähler manifolds with nef canonical bundle

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds, curvature, line-bundles

Are there examples of compact complex manifolds $X$ with $K_X$ nef, but $X$ is not Kähler? Perhaps even non-Moishezon examples?

Here, nef can be defined as follows: For any $\varepsilon>0$ there is a Hermitian metric $h_{\varepsilon}$ on $K_X$ with curvature $\Theta_{h_{\varepsilon}} \geq - \varepsilon \omega$, where $\omega$ is a positive-definite real $(1,1)$--form on $X$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $X$ and $Y$ be compact complex manifolds. Note that $K_{X\times Y} \cong \pi_1^*K_X\otimes \pi_2^*K_Y$. If $Y$ has trivial canonical bundle, then $K_{X\times Y} \cong \pi_1^*K_X$. Now the pullback of a nef line bundle is again nef, see Proposition 1.8 (i) of [*Compact Complex Manifolds with Numerically Effective Tangent Bundles*](https://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/%7Edemailly/manuscripts/dps1.pdf) by Demailly, Peternell, and Schneider. So one can construct many examples by choosing $X$ with $K_X$ nef and $Y$ non-Kähler with $K_Y$ trivial.

**Example:** Let $X$ be a curve of genus $g > 1$ and $Y$ be a primary Kodaira surface. Then $X\times Y$ is a non-Kähler threefold with $K_{X\times Y}$ nef. Note that $X\times Y$ is also not Moishezon as it contains $Y$ as a complex submanifold and $Y$ is not Moishezon.

For more examples of non-Kähler manifolds with $K_Y$ trivial, see the introduction of [*Non-Kähler Calabi-Yau Manifolds*](https://arxiv.org/abs/1401.4797) by Tosatti. As is pointed out in Proposition 1.1, if $K_Y$ is trivial (or even just torsion), then it admits a metric $h$ with curvature $\Theta_h = 0$ and hence $K_Y$ is nef, so we don't even need to take a product with $X$ in the above construction.

Comment: Thank you! This is a very nice answer! Thank you for taking the time :-)